# Pygbag producing Error occurred: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: python, pygbag

I have made a game using pygame and converted it to html using pygbag but this error continuesly occurs while game is running in background Error occurred: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause(). why is this happening.

I checked the documentation and didnt found the error. I also checked this but it didnt work either https://developer.chrome.com/blog/play-request-was-interrupted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Need more info, code and logs about what you're doing. Even better try searching in [Pygbag issues](https://github.com/pygame-web/pygbag/issues) to see if anyone else encountered the same issue before.

Comment: The html code is too big....

Comment: make an itch html5 project with `--archive` and send the url+password here

Comment: here take this zip file the html is in the build folder https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fFwvwZrgc-DMIaRoFUhXVRvQMEHOufZH/view?usp=drive_link